# Handling fetch errors in react native / redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I've set up my login action creator as follows.

A successful login happens in the try block with a `200` status. All failed logins end up in the catch block `401` and if I shutdown the server, the request returns `Network Error`.

Is there a better/standard way to handle this? Particularly because in a large application, there are obviously many different endpoints to request from, so it seems un-necessary to re-write the network error code each time.

```
export const handleLogin = data => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(
        `http://${SERVERURL}/auth/login`, data
    );
    console.log('200 status');
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: res.data });
    // AsyncStorage.setItem(JWT_BEARER_TOKEN, res.data.token);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.response && e.response.status === 401) {
      console.log('Login Failed');
      dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAILURE, payload: e.response.data });
    } else {
      console.error('Server / Network Error');
      dispatch({ type: NETWORK_ERROR, payload: e.response });
    }
  }
};
```

---

Update based on @Pritish Vaidya's answer.

So using your suggested answer, should I be handling login success fail like so?

```
export const handleLogin = data => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await axiosInstance.post('/auth/login', data);
  if (res.status && res.status === 200) {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: res.data });
  } else {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAILURE, payload: null });
  }
};
```

And figuring out how I can pass `dispatch` following the `Network Error` like  here:

```
// ...
}, (error) => {
  if (!error.response) {
    return dispatch({ type: 'NETWORK_FAILURE' payload: null });
  }
}
// ...
```

Comment: do you mean is how to use `Timeout` to catch `Network Error`?

Comment: I didn't know that there was a convention in using `Timeout`. What I'm getting at more so is should I have a `dealWithCatch()` function in my catch statement that dispatches `NETWORK_ERROR` if I get a `500` or `Network_Error`.

Comment: why you just not use axios? why you wrap it ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using `axios`, you can handle the errors in the following way.

Axios provides with the request [**middlewares / interceptors**](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors), with *an easy implementation*.

*Based on your question, you need a response middleware*

**Usage**

**Interceptor.js**

```
const AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: SERVER_URL,
    timeout: 20000,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})


 AxiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) =>{
    // handle the response after it is received
    return response;
}, (error) => {
    if (!error.response) {
        // Network error
        // handle the network error here
        // Get the instance of the store here
         store.dispatch(// Your action))
    }
    else {
        // handle the errors due to the status code here
        const code = error.response.status

        // handle the errors due to response data here
        const response = error.response.data
    }

})
export default AxiosInstance
```

Comment: Thanks, This is really helpful. based on your answer I've added my interpretation of how I think it should be implemented. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You can also pass the redux store instance to your `AxiosInstance`, and dispatch the actions there, if you want to log for network errors.